# Как найти количество способов набрать суму S из чисел в диапазоне от L до R?

Tags: c++, python, алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Передо мной постала вот такая задача:

> "Найти количество разложений числа S на числа в диапазоне от L - R"

И я недавно видел задачу про разложения с помощью ДП, идея в том чтобы разбить сумму на меншие которые зависят от предыдущих, если мы хотим набрать суму S из чисел 1, 2, 3 .. k, то **cntS = cntS - 1 + cntS - 2 + cntS - 3 .. + cntS + k**. Из этого достаточно просто опредилить значения cntS.

Но как быть если нам дан диапазон чисел от L до R, тобеш **cntS = (cntS - R) + (cntS - R - 1) + (cntS - R - 2)  ... + (cntS - L)**.

Comment: Ну так последнее предложение - и есть заготовка для динамического программирования

Comment: Надо пощитать cntR и cntL и тогда cntLR = cntR - cntL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как получить сумму `S`? Из числа `S-L` и `L`, из числа `S-L-1` и `L+1`, ..., из числа `S - R` и `R`. Таким образом, количество способов набрать сумму

```
F(S) = F(S-L) + F(S-L-1) +.. F(S-R)
```

Для каждого слагаемого рекурсивно решим ту же самую задачу, пока не дойдём до значения `S=0`, для которого количество способов равно единице.

Посчитанные значения `F(x)` будем запоминать, чтобы не пересчитывать много раз - вот и мемоизация, или top-down ДП (в Python можно `@functools.lru_cache` использовать)

Набросок с контролем вариантов (различающиеся порядком считаются за разные)

```
def numways(s, l, r, st):
    if s < 0:
        return 0
    if s == 0:
        print(st)
        return 1
    res = 0
    for i in range(l, min(s+1, r+1)):
        res += numways(s - i, l, r, st + str(i))
    return res

print(numways(8,2,4,""))
```

Comment: MBo,а можете код написать для наглядности? Не думаю что это будёт очеень сложно для вас :)

Comment: А можно как то оптимизировать, мне не нужно самые разложения,а только их количество? (PS : различающиеся порядком считаются за разные) уже для чисел порядка n=100,l=1,r=2 считает оочень долго

Comment: Строка введена для отладки на малых числах, потом её надо убрать. А про запоминание я написал уже.