# Эффективный по времени алгоритм для решения «задачи о сумме подмножеств»

Tags: c, алгоритм, множества

A – множество целых чисел, B – подмножество множества A, состоящее из констатного числа элементов. N – количество элементов множества A, S – сумма элементов подмножества B.

То есть B – подмножество множества A, имеющее n элементов, где n < N, сумма которых равняется S.

N – 36, P – число бит для кодирования наибольшего числа множества A – 7.

Требуется определить количество подмножеств B и найти их. Упрощая, задача звучит так: нужно найти такие элементы из заданного набора, чтобы их количество равнялось n, а сумма была строго равна S.

Можете подсказать наиболее эффективный алгоритм для решения этой задачи?

**Обновление**: так сейчас выглядит функция (динамическое программрование):

```
int results[A_SET_SIZE][B_SET_SUM];
for (size_t i = 0; i < A_SET_SIZE; i++) {
    results[0][B_SET_SUM - 1] = 0;
}
for (size_t i = 1; i < A_SET_SIZE; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < B_SET_SUM; j++) {
        if (j > A[i]) {
            results[i][j] = max(results[i - 1][j], results[i - 1][j - A[i]] + A[i]);
        } else {
            results[i][j] = results[i - 1][j];
        }
    }
}
```

По формуле сочетаний удалось определить общее количество подмножеств с необходимым числом элементов – но как найти подходящие? Или, вернее, как найти среди них все те подмножества, что также удовлетворяют ограничению по сумме?

Пример: множество состоит из 4 элементов (A = {1, 2, 3, 4}). Нужно найти все такие подмножества, мощность которых равна 2, а сумма – 5. Получается, этим условиям удовлетворяют два подмножества: {1, 4} и {2, 3}. Задача именно в том, чтобы найти такие подмножества.

Comment: Если значения целые, то динамическое программирование

Comment: Подмножество - это маска или набор различных элементов? Если множество {1,1,1,1}, выбираем 3 элемента с суммой 3, то ответ 1 или 4? Или там изначально одинаковых элементов нет?

Comment: Надо помимо значения максимума хранить способ перехода. Кстати, а почему тут вообще максимум?

Comment: Насчет масок — подозреваю, это больше про реализацию, чем про сам алгоритм, если я правильно Вас понял. В данном случае, кажется, это неважно, потому что по маске можно восстановить значения, но оперировать подмножествами с уже внесёнными элементами, пожалуй, проще. Во множестве отсутствуют повторяющиеся значения, однако многократное использование одних и тех же элементов в подмножестве допускается. Формулировка задачи предполагает ограничение суммы элементов подмножества, — вроде, это вполне типично (та же задача о рюкзаке).

Comment: "многократное использование одних и тех же элементов в подмножестве" - звучит противоречиво. Или (под)множество, или сочетание с повторениями. Нужно уточнить постановку задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для демонстрации подхода с динамическим программированием:

```
def findsums(l, n, summ):
    a = [[] for i in range(summ + 1)]  
    a[0].append((0,0))
    for v in l:
        for i in range(summ, v-1,-1):
            for p in a[i - v]:
                if p[1] < n:
                    a[i].append((v, p[1] + 1))
    print(a)
    return

findsums([1,2,3,4,5],2,5)

[[(0, 0)], [(1, 1)], [(2, 1)], [(2, 2), (3, 1)], [(3, 2), (4, 1)], [(3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 1)]]
```

Ячейки `a` содержат списки туплей (можно вместо списка туплей использовать мап или массив), в которых первый элемент - последнее использованное значение из списка, а второй - количество чисел в наборе, составляющий данную сумму. Сумма соответствует индексу ячейки

В последней ячейке списка лежит три варианта составить сумму 5, но третий - из одного слагаемого (я добавил в список 5), и не подходит.
Вариант (3, 2) означает, что сумма 5 составлена из двух слагаемых, последнее из которых 3. Для получения набора слагаемых записываем 3, переходим в 5-3=2 ячейку. Там лежит (2, 1), значит, ещё одно слагаемое - 2. Аналогично находим вариант из слагаемых [4,1]

Comment: Кажется, при `v = 1`, то есть при первой итерации, значения `i` будут находится в пределе `[0; 5]`, соответственно, в строке `for p in a[i - v]` программа попытается обратиться к `a[-1]`.

Comment: @Marionette Список обходится в обратном порядке, последнее значение i будет 1 (второй аргумент for в Python **не** входит в перечисление)

Comment: Точно, извините, – нечасто приходится сталкиваться с `Python`. Есть еще вопрос – уточните, пожалуйста, функционирует ли алгоритм с произвольными множествами? Говоря в контексте `C` – `{'0','1','2','a','b'}`, например, – не совсем разобрался. В этом случае требуется, чтобы сумма символов, вернее, их кодов, равнялась определенной сумме.

Comment: Да, будет, если на Python использовать ord('0') и т.д. для получения кода символов

Comment: Большое время работы и огромное потребление памяти при мощности множества – 36, n – 12 и summ – 900. Хотя, судя по сложности, O(ns), работать должно весьма быстро.

Comment: Сам подмножества действительно все нужны? При их хранении сложность намного выше.

Comment: Суть задачи в том, чтобы генерировать разные неповторяющиеся последовательности символов, удовлетворяющие следующим условиям: размер, сумма кодов. Поэтому важно обеспечить возможность получения случайных последовательностей. Скажем, формулировка задачи не обязывает просчитывать все комбинации заранее, но, опять же, необходимо, чтобы они получались разными и за разумное время.

Comment: Ну вот, это не та задача, что описана в условии. Генерировать последовательность наборов с данной суммой - это задача Integer Partition - получение всех разбиений числа на данные слагаемые, она не требует хранения наборов.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать ресурс, на котором представлена примерная реализация? Нашел описание на сайте ИТМО, но математической базы, видимо, недостаточно, чтобы воплотить описанные идеи.

Comment: Генерация разбиений - задача, которая имеет простое рекурсивное решение ([пример для одного из вариантов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962199/Как-найти-количество-способов-набрать-суму-s-из-чисел-в-диапазоне-от-l-до-r/962218#962218), [для другого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1102213/Все-варианты-сложения-элементов-массива/1102226#1102226)). Но, вероятно, стоит задать новый вопрос, точно сформулировав условия.

Answer (score 0):

Эта задача решается с помощью meet-in-the-middle. [Задача о рюкзаке](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Meet-in-the-middle#.D0.97.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B0_.D0.BE_.D1.80.D1.8E.D0.BA.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.BA.D0.B5). Работает за 2^{n/2}.

Однако, если число S невелико, можно использовать динамическое программирование, получится обычная задача о рюкзаке. В таком случае время работы будет составлять O(nS)

Comment: Вы имеете в виду именно n – необходимое количество элементов в подмножестве B, – или все же N – мощность множества A? Если N, то, кажется, для первого алгоритма потребуется весьма много времени и памяти.

Comment: По ссылке указано, что полное число N

Comment: Задача о рюкзаке принадлежит к NP-полным, поэтому алгоритм за 2^n это нормально. Вы не указали ограничения на числа, которые могут быть даны. n это мощность A, то есть n = N. По времени зайдет, с теми ограничениями, которые показали вы.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, подробнее описать применение динамического программирования? Нашел довольно много статей, но не совсем понял принцип работы и, соответственно, есть трудности с реализацией (обновил вопрос, посмотрите). Скажем, по формуле сочетаний удалось определить количество подмножеств с необходимым числом элементов, но как их найти? Или, вернее, как найти среди них все то, что также удовлетворяют ограничению по сумме?

Comment: С помощью динамического программирования можно посчитать только количество подходящих наборов, а вам нужно их вывести. Количество наборов может быть довольно велико, чтобы все наборы вывести нужно написать просто перебор.

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать динамику по двум состояниям `dp[i][j]`, где **i** это сумма взытых элементов, и мы использовали предметы с индексами не больше **j**. Тогда ответом будет `dp[S][N]`. Мы учтем все множества с суммой равной **S**, но так же если **сумма A** равна **S** то мы посчитаем и полное множество. При случае когда суммы равны нам надо просто вычесть один вариант.

```
dp[0][0] = 1;
for(int j = 1; j <= N; ++j) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= S; ++i){
        if(A[j] <= i){
            dp[i][j] += dp[i - A[j]][j - 1];
        }
    }
}
int ans = dp[S][N];
if(sum(A) == S) {
    ans--;
}
```

**Внимание, индексы в множестве A нумеруются с 1**