# Все варианты сложения элементов массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

У меня есть массив, нужно найти все варианты сложения элементов массива, которые равны 1000.

```
1000 = 500 + 500
1000 = 500 + 200 + 200 + 100
1000 = 500 + 200 + 100 + 100 +100
```

Пример:

```
let number = 1000;
let array = [100, 200, 500];
```

Comment: Непростая задача, между прочим)

Comment: Нужно отсортировать массив по убыванию. По количеству элементов получить число 0<<n, а затем перебирать каждый вариант этого числа представляя его в виде двоичного числа, где каждый бит (если 1) по номеру извлекает значение из массива, складывает все и сравнивает с 1000. На C так получалось быстрее всего)) Если каждого числа может быть несколько, то вначале дополнить массив так, чтобы это число повторялось пока их сумма не больше 1000. Итого в массиве здесь должно быть 500 -2 шт, 200 -5шт, 100 -10шт. 2 в степени 17 количество вариантов))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может перемудрил, но код рабочий!

Суть подхода - перебор всех возможных вариантов сочетаний.
Варианты сочетаний можно представить в виде битовых карт. Например: 8 это 2^3 то есть три бита 111 дает следующие сочетания для массива `[500,200,100]`:

```
 000, 001, 111, 010, 011, 100, 110, 101.
```

Подставьте вместо каждой единички соответствующее (по index) значение и получится:

```
[], [100], [500,200,100], [200], [200,100],[500], [500,200], [500,100].
```

Если б числа не повторялись, то было бы 8 вариантов, отбрасываем 000 - 7 вариантов.

Чтобы перебрать все варианты, сначала наполняем массив значениями, так, чтобы сумма каждого в отдельности множества элементов не превышала итог:

```
[500,500, 200,200,200,200,200, 100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]
```

И получаем, что вариантов сочетаний этих элементов 2^17 - 1 (все 0), то есть 1<<17 - 1, то есть: 11111111111111111 в битовом выражении (не включая все 0).
Дальше проходимся по этим битовым маскам и заменяем 1 в маске, на соответствующие значения (по индексу) в массиве. Сравниваем их сумму с необходимым итогом и записываем или нет в `variants` их строковое представление ( для Set каждый отдельный объект является уникальным, поэтому сами одинаковые (для нас) массивы он не отбрасывает).

```js
let number = 1000;
let array = [500, 200, 100];
array.sort((a,b) => a - b);  // сортируем в обратном порядке
let arr = []; // пустой массив для получения всех элементов, которые можно поместить в number

array.forEach( a => {// Дополняем массив повторными значениями, сумма которых не превышает number
 for(let i=0; i< Math.floor(number/a); i++){
   arr.push(a);
  }
});

let variantsNum = 1 << arr.length; // Считаем количество вариантов
let variants = new Set(); // Объявляем Набор для неповторяющихся элементов

for(let i=1; i < variantsNum; i++){ // Перебираем все варианты, формируя битовые карты для подстановок
  let n = variantsNum;
  let count = arr.length;
  let variant = [];
  while(n > 0){
    if(i & n) variant.push(arr[count]); // Ищем 1 в битовой карте
    n = n >> 1; // Смещаем на один разряд
    count--;
  }
  if(sum(variant) == number){  // Если равно number, то добавляем строку
    variants.add(variant.join()); // Строку в дальнейшем можно преобразовать в массив
  }
}


function sum(arr){
 return arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
}

console.log([...variants]);  // ВЫВОДИМ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ РАБОТЫ
```

Помимо этого выложу и переработанный код, предложенный `MBo`. В нем задается массив деталей определенной длины и количество каждой из них. Функция берет количество деталей в этом пределе. Может, кому пригодится.

```js
class Detail {             // Создаем класс для деталей
  constructor(len, num){
    this.len = len;
    this.num = num;
  }
}

let details = [           // Забиваем массив новыми деталями, порядок не важен, позже будет сортировка
  new Detail(1400,3),
  new Detail(1100,4),
  new Detail(1000,4),
  new Detail(1050,4),
  new Detail(1010,4),
  new Detail(900,4),
  new Detail(800,4),
  new Detail(700,4),
  new Detail(500,10),
  new Detail(400,8),
  new Detail(300,10),
  new Detail(200,4)
]

details.sort((a,b) => a.len - b.len); // Сортировка по возрастанию `len`

let variants = [];     // Здесь будут накапливаться все варианты

function getAllChains(dets, sum, last, l){

 // Для себя в этом месте я добавил проверку на длину массива и добавлял все варианты (в моем случае не надо ждать совпадения с суммой, она маловероятна)
//if(l.length > 0){
//  variants1.push(l);
   // } else
  if(sum == 0){        // Скидываем накопленный массив, если остаток 0
    variants.push(l);
    return;
  }

  for(let i = last; i < dets.length; i++){
    if(dets[i].len > sum || dets[i].num == 0) break; // Дополнительно проверяем наличие деталей
    dets[i].num--;  // Убавляем количество текущей детали
    let l1 = [...l];
    l1.push(dets[i].len);
    getAllChains(dets, sum - dets[i].len, i, l1);
    dets[i].num++;  // Возвращаем после рекурсии
  }
  
}

getAllChains(details, 2700, 0, []);

console.log(`Variants' num: ${variants.length}`);
console.log(variants);
```

Comment: Рабочий и понятный для такого новичка как я... Супер!!!!! Спасибо огромное

Comment: Код рассчитан на неповторяющиеся входные данные, а здесь много лишней работы, но пока значений не много - работает.

Comment: А не подскажете, что означает вот это для номеров вариантов - let variantsNum = 1 << arr.length;

Comment: Добавляем разряды, то есть `2` в степени `arr.length`

Comment: @ЕрвандС-ян, добавил разъяснения к коду.

Comment: @Leonid Всё чётко и с пояснениями. Хороший ответ.

Comment: К сожалению, для суммы всего втрое больше решить таким методом уже нереально.

Comment: @MBo   Я говорю есть избыточность в этом коде, по сути надо оперировать тремя элементами, а не 17)) подставляя определенное их количество в итоговый массив. Для заданных параметров чересчур избыточный, но хотел выразить в коде, что писал на словах...

Comment: @MBo, буду очень благодарен (без всякой иронии) если выразите в коде ваше решение, для меня это важно - я перманентно улучшаю свою программу листового раскроя, где такой подбор - важнейшая функция, повторяющаяся тысячи раз... У меня, конечно, сначала идет анализ, устанавливаются range, которые точно не будут превышать необходимую сумму. Ограничиваю количество входных данных до 22, опытным путем, если больше, то существенно возрастает время обработки. Все это в C, конечно.

Comment: @Leonid Привёл код на Python, надеюсь, будет нетрудно переложить на другие языки.

Answer (score 7):

Можно на каждом шаге сводить задачу к меньшей размерности.

Например, с помощью рекурсии

```
(Варианты составить сумму 1000) = 
       ([500] + Варианты составить сумму (1000 - 500)) + 
       ([200] + Варианты составить сумму (1000 - 200)) + 
       ([100] + Варианты составить сумму (1000 - 100)) +
```

Пример. Начало цикла с индекса last позволяет избежать повторов.

```js
let variants = []
//arr сортирован
function parts(arr, sum, last, l){
  if(sum == 0){
    //console.log(l);
    variants.push(l);
    return;
  }

  for(let i = last; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] > sum) break;
    parts(arr, sum - arr[i], i, l + " "+arr[i]);
  }
}

parts([100,200,500], 1000, 0, "");
console.log(variants);
```

Кроме того, в определённых условиях выгодно хранить уже сгенерированные варианты для сочетаний параметров (sum, набор) и использовать их (нужна память, конечно)

Comment: `let arr = [1,3,7];
let sum = 15;

function parts(arr, sum, last, l){
  if(sum < 0){
   return l;
  }
  
  for(let i = last; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] > sum) break;
    l.push(arr[i]);
    parts(arr, sum - arr[i], i, [...l]);
  }
}

let variants = parts(arr, sum, 0, []);

console.log(variants);` Что не так? Не работает у меня, синтаксис не знакомый. https://jsfiddle.net/efimleonid/owkvbf3y/11/

Comment: Будьте так добры, добавьте сниппет с JS рабочим кодом)) Ничего не ясно, где он передает массивы элементов и использует затем.

Comment: Не все работает, надо еще поковыряться. Но мысль я понял, большое спасибо. Я с этого и начинал)) потом переделал по другому.

Comment: Вот это `l.push(arr[i])` неверно, т.к. элемент нужн добавлять к копии списка, которая передаётся на следующий уровень рекурсии. Однако можно и модифицировать единственный список, но после возврата из рекурсии удалять то, что добавляли.

Comment: @Leonid На JS сделал

Comment: Ага, отлично, работает. Сейчас разберусь как))) Для ответа может подправите на 1000, 500, 200, 100?

Comment: @Leonid Подправлю, но какая разница, кроме лишних нулей

Comment: Для соответствия заданию)). Всё, я поковырял и изменил, у меня не строки, а массивы и сохраняются все(не только равные sum), а потом отбираются самые длинные сколько-то. Вот только мне нельзя так просто брать сколько хочешь деталей определенного размера. Работаю над `{len: 100, num: 4}`. То есть деталь длиной 100 можно взять не более 4 шт. Должно получиться. СПАСИБО ПРЕОГРОМНОЕ!

Comment: Ребят, а как можно войти во внутр таких функций и получить данные внутри? Ну например получить массив l, в которой хранятся уже варианты и отсортировать их, выбрать только нужные... а то множество элементов массива уже все летает

Comment: @Ерванд С-ян Как это лучше сделать в JS - я не знаю. Полный вариант находится в `if(sum == 0)`, частично собранный - перед циклом, новые варианты образуются внутри цикла. А что значит - нужные, какие критерии??

Comment: А ваш код разве не на JS написано?  Я имел ввиду например как получить данные консольки? Список вариантов, они же в массиве l

Comment: @Ерванд С-ян На JS, но я не спец в нём, не уверен, что хороший вариант могу предложить. Вот там, где печатается `l`, его можно добавить в массив вариантов (получится массив массивов или что-то подобное). Модифицировал код в ответе (если я правильно понял, что нужно). В данным момент это массив строк, а как `l` компоновать, как массив - тут я не подскажу.

Comment: Ну строку в массив превращать не трудно со split-ом, только логику не уловил, ведь l - это в параметрах массив, как превращается в строку в функции

Comment: Ой, да чего только в вашем JS само по себе не превращается ;) Поменял на строку, но по семантике нужен массив, и в рекурсивном вызове должен подставляться массив с добавленным элементом (см. Python версию в редакции 3 в истории правок)